# Copy To Clipboard Using Javascript on my website and should support all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy

Below code I'm using for copy to clipboard but it doesn't work in safari ?

```
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, Safari, the new Internet Explorer.

Comment: Try focusing the textarea before calling the `select()` method.